# Apply discount on highest price in the cart

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cart-rule

I am working a project a where i need to set discount on the highest price in the cart i have looked in to shopping cart price rules for this but cant find such a thing like this.

Is there i need a custom coding for this? Any one having any idea for on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed. You need a module which will do it. Assuming that you know how to write a Magento module I would suggest to observe `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` event:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
            <observers>
                <your_module>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Your_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>salesQuoteAddressCollectTotalsBefore</method>
                </your_module>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Loop through the items:

```
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
$quote_items = $quote->getItemsCollection();

foreach ($quote_items as $item) {
    ...
}
```

Find out the most expansive one and apply a discount using `$item->setCustomPrice($new_price)` and/or `$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price)`  methods.

You may also need to set `$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true)` afterwards.

> Grau, teurer Freund, ist alle Theorie, und Grün des Lebens goldner Baum.

This code is only a theory and not tested live. So field work is left to you. But if you will have problems implementing it please let me know and I will put some more life into it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this code snippet this will surely help me reaching some where in this journey, i will let you know if i found trouble.

Comment: How to get the posted data in sales_quote_collect_totals_before observer i am trying Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('XXX'); this but not working

Comment: What kind of data do you need?